# The time asked of the question isn't accurate

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, questions

So I asked a question on `stackoverflow.com` yesterday and it got answered yesterday, and it became a long forgotten post.

I wanted to re-check the answer when i noticed that this question was asked today and is also active today , but it wasn't.

**Note: More than 24 hours passed**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time stamps for all of the posts (question and answers) on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425557/hide-buttons-when-printing) are **just** under 24 hours (at this time - in about 15 minutes, it will indeed be 24 hours).

The timestamp for the question is `2015-07-15 08:43:59Z`. The UTC time right now is `2015-07-16 08:27:59Z`

There is no bug here.